# How to change separator in multi select

Tags: select, forms, separator

It is a little like http://webix.com/snippet/e3ed3929, except the 'separator' attribute is not working in 'form:select'

```
<display:table name="viewBean.fileList"  id="filebean" requestURI="test.htm"  >
    <display:column  titleKey=".....">
            <form:select path="profiles">...
```

There are many select dropdown in this table. Usually server side get value like 'a,b,c...'. But now I hope to get values like 'a;b;c...'.

Question: how to change this separator.

Thank you.

Comment: what browser are you using? looks like that could be a browser issue. with chrome it works fine.

Comment: I try Chrome and IE. Do you mean you try in the link I posted directly?

Comment: Yes, I clicked the link to the sample using GChrome and am seeing ';' as delimiter

Comment: I know little about that link, how do you test? Add code in the 'HTML Code' part?